# How to find the range of dates for each group in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, dplyr, summarize

Consider this data frame:

```r
data <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], c(4,5,4)),
                Date = as.Date(c("2010-08-09", "2010-09-11", "2010-09-12", "2010-09-18",
                                 "2014-03-15","2014-03-16","2014-03-20","2014-03-21","2014-03-25",
                                 "2016-05-02","2016-08-02","2016-08-03","2016-09-21")))
```

We have three groups with observations that were taken on various dates. I want to find the first and last date for each group (preferably using `dplyr`). How can this be done with dates?

Edit:
I am adding this to clarify my reason for asking, which has to do with R's ability to interpret real time (dates). `data2` will be the exact same as `data` above, but notice that I switch the first two dates, so that the observations for `group==a` are no longer in real temporal order (from earliest to latest, in relation to real time):

```r
data2 <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], c(4,5,4)),
                Date = as.Date(c("2010-09-11","2010-08-09", "2010-09-12", "2010-09-18",
                                 "2014-03-15","2014-03-16","2014-03-20","2014-03-21","2014-03-25",
                                 "2016-05-02","2016-08-02","2016-08-03","2016-09-21")))
```

So September 11, 2010 comes after August 9, 2010 (real time), but they are not in this temporal order in the data frame.
Now if we do:

```r
library(dplyr)
data2%>%group_by(group) %>% summarise(FirsDate=first(Date),LastDate=last(Date))
```

We get:

```r
  group FirsDate   LastDate  
  <fct> <date>     <date>    
1 a     2010-09-11 2010-09-18
2 b     2014-03-15 2014-03-25
3 c     2016-05-02 2016-09-21
```

So it returned the first and last observations, not in true temporal order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest an approach using `first()` and `last()` functions from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
data <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], c(4,5,4)),
                   Date = as.Date(c("2010-08-09", "2010-09-11", "2010-09-12", "2010-09-18",
                                    "2014-03-15","2014-03-16","2014-03-20","2014-03-21","2014-03-25",
                                    "2016-05-02","2016-08-02","2016-08-03","2016-09-21")))
#Code
data %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(FirsDate=first(Date),LastDate=last(Date))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
   group Date       FirsDate   LastDate  
   <fct> <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 a     2010-08-09 2010-08-09 2010-09-18
 2 a     2010-09-11 2010-08-09 2010-09-18
 3 a     2010-09-12 2010-08-09 2010-09-18
 4 a     2010-09-18 2010-08-09 2010-09-18
 5 b     2014-03-15 2014-03-15 2014-03-25
 6 b     2014-03-16 2014-03-15 2014-03-25
 7 b     2014-03-20 2014-03-15 2014-03-25
 8 b     2014-03-21 2014-03-15 2014-03-25
 9 b     2014-03-25 2014-03-15 2014-03-25
10 c     2016-05-02 2016-05-02 2016-09-21
11 c     2016-08-02 2016-05-02 2016-09-21
12 c     2016-08-03 2016-05-02 2016-09-21
13 c     2016-09-21 2016-05-02 2016-09-21
```

If you just want the variables by each group you can use `summarise()`:

```
#Code2
data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(FirsDate=first(Date),LastDate=last(Date))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group FirsDate   LastDate  
  <fct> <date>     <date>    
1 a     2010-08-09 2010-09-18
2 b     2014-03-15 2014-03-25
3 c     2016-05-02 2016-09-21
```

**Update:**

```
#Code
data2 %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(FirsDate=min(Date),LastDate=max(Date))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group FirsDate   LastDate  
  <fct> <date>     <date>    
1 a     2010-08-09 2010-09-18
2 b     2014-03-15 2014-03-25
3 c     2016-05-02 2016-09-21
```

Comment: so if i understand correctly, R already knows how to sort by dates correctly as long as the data is of class date. Is this correct? It is obvious here that if you group by `group`, and find the first and last observation, they will also have the first and last `Date`, in actual temporal order, because that is the way I happened to create them. But if you apply this to a dataframe where observations may not be in "real" temporal order, will R still know to find the first and last (i.e., earliest and latest) `Date` in relation to real time?

Comment: @Ryan Yes you are right! You only need that your variables are of class date.

Comment: I actually found this to not work, please see my updated question

Comment: @Ryan I have added an update to the answer! Please check and let me know if that works. I think it is better to use `min()` and `max()` functions in order to assimilate times!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
#   group Date      
# <chr> <date>    
# 1 a     2010-08-09
# 2 a     2010-09-18
# 3 b     2014-03-15
# 4 b     2014-03-25
# 5 c     2016-05-02
# 6 c     2016-09-21
```